# Can I identify users in front of an information screen to depict user related data using BLE? If so, how?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an information screen application implemented in java. When a user is in a certain range of the information screen, I want to depict user related data on the information screen. It should also work for multiple users in front of the screen. I am trying to implement that with BLE. The users should have an app, which configures the BLE. The information screen should be connected to a BLE module. Also the information screen should recognize if a user has gotten out of range and therefore it should not show the related data of that user anymore.

My current different approaches are:

1. information screen ble module as peripheral and user-app as central
   The information screen advertises its existance, the central connects to it and writes an identification token to the peripheral. This identification token is passed from the peripheral to the java application. The central disconnects, in case there are other users in front of the information screen and the peripheral starts advertising again.
2. information screen ble module as central and user-app as peripheral
   The central scans for all peripherals and tries to connect to them. If connected the central reads the identification token from the service of the peripheral and passes the token to the java application.
3. information screen as ble beacon and user-app as observer
   The beacon broadcasts data and the observer scans for it. If the observer receives the beacon data the observer sends its identification token directly to the java application.

Am I on the right track or is this not doable? What do you think about the different approaches? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think option 2 would work best in practise and have the lowest latency.

Both Android and iOS can advertise. See http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2020/05/07/hacking-the-overflow-area though for how to detect iOS background advertisers.

Option 3 would result in many seconds of latency, at least on Android since the scan interval is so long in the background.

Option 1 could work as long as you only have one single (or just a few) information screen. In this case you set up a pending connection on the central side that never times out.